# django-q does not stop with Ctrl-C

Tags: python, django, django-q

i installed django-q version 0.9.4 but i can not stop qcluster with Ctrl+C.

```
Q_CLUSTER = {
    'name': 'DjangORM',
    'sync' : False,
    'orm': 'default',
    'retry': 18000,

}
```

```
15:43:57 [Q] ERROR reincarnated worker Process-1:8 after death
15:43:57 [Q] ERROR reincarnated worker Process-1:17 after death
15:43:57 [Q] ERROR reincarnated worker Process-1:19 after death
15:43:57 [Q] ERROR reincarnated monitor Process-1:21 after sudden death
15:43:58 [Q] ERROR reincarnated pusher Process-1:22 after sudden death
15:43:58 [Q] ERROR reincarnated worker Process-1:14 after death
15:43:58 [Q] ERROR reincarnated worker Process-1:20 after death
15:43:59 [Q] ERROR reincarnated worker Process-1:18 after death
15:44:01 [Q] INFO Process-1:24 ready for work at 9312
15:44:01 [Q] INFO Process-1:23 ready for work at 4432
```

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: @Prateek Jha Unfortunately, I did not find any way and the process had to be killed completely. Use django-celery.

Answer (score 0):

Use **CTRL-BREAK**. CTRL-C doesn't work.

Alternatively, you can kill all python apps (aggressive and will also kill your web container - CTRL-BREAK is cleaner):

```
taskkill /im python.exe /f
```

Comment: CTRL-BREAK didn't work for me either. I use Windows 10.

Comment: **CTRL-BREAK** does not work in Windows at all, I have Windows 11, I tested it in other windows as well. Works well on Linux.

Comment: There is no proper fix to this yet?